how to install drivers for MEDIATEK in ubuntu 24.04 (linux 6.8.0-41generic)
-network UNCLAIMED
product-Mediatek
version- 01
bit depth-64 bits
frequency-33mhz

You've provided release, but not product details (Server? Desktop?) nor any clues as to what type of device.. Mediatek make screens, wifi and more... but given no clue as to command your paste is from, NOR type of device type you're trying to use...

Not sure. I end up canibalizing a nice Ahteros wlan module from a broken laptop laying around and I now enjoy my wifi in Ubuntu 24.

Did you insert the Atheros WLAN module into a mini PCIe or M.2 slot, or did you use a USB adaptor?
